# Use script only on specific sheet not on all sheets in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following script to make a stamp with editors email in column 6 when column 7 is changed

```
function onedit(e) {
  var r = e.range;
  if( r.getColumn() != 6 ) { //checks the column
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-07:00", "yyyy-MM-dd, hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(r.getRow(),6).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  }
 }
```

But it functions on all sheets. I would like it to only function on a sheet named VD Gaps.
Can someone help out with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `onEdit(e)` function only do its thing on the 'VD Gaps' sheet like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 7
    || !e.range.getSheet().getName().match(/^(VD Gaps)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

Please note that the `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). Simple triggers run in a restricted context where the identity of the user at the keyboard is usually not available. *"They may or may not be able to determine the identity of the current user, depending on a complex set of security restrictions."* See [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()) and [Session.getEffectiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser).

Comment: Thanks! 
Works perfect. 

I am not using onedit in the script. Just added it to make it easy for people here to handle the code.